# Archived 2014 repository not contains sha512 file

Tags: tlmgr

I have installed LaTeX 2016 on Debian Stretch (ruby 2.5 docker image) and I would like install packages from 2014 repository (ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2014/tlnet-final), but when I tried install something, I see this error:

```
/usr/bin/tlmgr: cannot download: download did not succeed: 
ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2014/tlnet-final/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb.sha512
```

Problem is, that the new `tlmgr` does not support md5 files and requires sha512 files, but in repository aren't sha512 files. How can I solve it?

I tried set `no-checksums=1` in the config file, but it doesn't help. I'm not sure if the config file has correct location; also I'm not sure if `no-checksums=1` should help.

I tried these locations for the config file:

```
/usr/local/share/texmf/texmf.cnf
/root/texmf/texmf.cnf
/root/.texlive2016/texmf-config
/etc/texmf/texmf.cnf


kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFSYSCONFIG
/etc/texmf

kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFCONFIG
/root/.texlive2016/texmf-config
```

My steps:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y texlive-base texlive-bibtex-extra
tlmgr init-usertree
tlmgr option repository ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2014/tlnet-final
tlmgr install babel-czech
```

LaTeX and `tlmgr` version:

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Debian)
tlmgr revision 41476 (2016-06-18 02:45:25 +0200)
tlmgr using installation: /usr/share/texlive
TeX Live (http://tug.org/texlive) version 2016
```

**Edit: Question isn't about upgrading TL, but using an archived repository from more recent TL. So I disagree, that it is a duplicate question. Question is how to use the archived repository from 2014 with TL 2016. In `tlmgr` it is possible to set archived repository.**

Comment: We are in 2018, soon there will be TL 2018, so is there any need to get TL 2014 when having TL 2106 installed?

Comment: In Debian Stretch is default TL 2016 (https://packages.debian.org/stretch/texlive-base), so therefore TL 2016. And I need repository from 2014, because I'm using it for auto-generating PDF documents, and it doesn't work correctly with new packages. It was developed in 2013-2014 years, but I need upgrade ruby only. But question is, how to use old repository with new TL? Because sha512 isn't in old repository. Maybe I should install somehow TL 2014.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to this turns out to be: in the historic folders, there seems to be an `install-tl` matching each version of Texlive, so just use that one.

For instance, if you want to install Texlive 2015, it is at:

- ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2015

If you browse those folders a bit, you will find the `install-tl` package here:

- ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2015/tlnet-final/install-tl-unx.tar.gz

So you can do:

```
$ wget ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2015/tlnet-final/install-tl-unx.tar.gz
...
$ tar xzvf install-tl-unx.tar.gz 
install-tl-20160405/
install-tl-20160405/readme-txt.dir/
install-tl-20160405/readme-txt.dir/README.SR
...
$ TEXLIVE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$(pwd)/texlive ./install-tl-20160405/install-tl --repository=ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2015/tlnet-final --force-arch=i386-linux
Overriding platform to i386-linux
Loading ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2015/tlnet-final/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
Installing TeX Live 2015 from: ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2015/tlnet-final
Platform: i386-linux => 'GNU/Linux on Intel x86'       ### without force-arch: Platform: x86_64-linux => 'GNU/Linux on x86_64'
Distribution: net  (downloading)
...
```

Comment: Had the same problem as the original author and this worked for me, even in 2021.
Thanks!